# Missing scope in access token - code flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to execute `Oauth2 code flow` to get access token but not able to fetch built-in email `scope`.

Below is my setup.

1. I have registered an application in Azure Active Directory.  Lets say app id is  - `APP1`
2. I am using V2 endpoint to access 'code' from 'authorize'endpoint.

Below is piece of code

```
[HttpPost]  
    public IActionResult Index(MyModel myModel)
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var authEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my-tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=APP1&response_type=code&scope=openid+email";

        return Redirect(authEndpoint);

    }

    public IActionResult Callback(string code, string error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("callback");
        AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/9e8754b6-f9cd-4aed-974d-a0ec0f3ed703");
        ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential("APP1", "xxxxxxx/_");
        var resource = "c4887ff4-f750-4f1b-9781-744affe6fee2";
        var r = context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource,cc).Result;
        var tokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/9e8754b6-f9cd-4aed-974d-a0ec0f3ed703/oauth2/v2.0/token";
        return Ok("");

    }
```

Note that I am requesting two scopes `openid` and `email`

I am getting callback with appropriate `code` which I am trading further to retrieve access token using ADAL library.

I am getting back the access token but scope is missing in the access token .  Please see below snap.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong method on the confidential client app object. You aren't using the code value.
So you are acquiring a token through client credentials flow, which never has scopes since it is an app-only flow.
Use the method/overload that accepts an authorisation code :)